# If Google Cloud SDK is uninstalled from Google Cloud Shell how to install it again?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

While working on Qwiklabs, when I am trying commands like `gcloud init` or using commands `gcloud`, `gsutil` or `bq`, I am getting error: "`gcloud command is not found`".

I think I mistakenly have uninstalled SDK from Cloud Shell.

Comment: In my Cloud Shell, gcloud is in /usr/bin.  Did you explicitly delete the GCP SDK?  When I run `apt list --installed` ... I find `google-cloud-sdk` in my installed list.

Comment: I am new to google cloud , I think I have unistalled cloud SDK from shell. Now I have installed it but it shows same error again. When i run command like gcloud init , gsutil, bq etc it say me that *gcloud command not found* . In which directory i have to install cloud sdk?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, restart Cloud Shell from the 3 dots on the right hand side

[image]

This action will restore your Cloud Shell home directory to a clean state using a new VM as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell?hl=en#resetting). This includes gcloud, gsutil or bq command functionality.

Comment: I ran qwiklab 2 times , still I have to restart cloud shell again???